# Array Problem. Code looks correct wrong output

Tags: java, arrays

This code looks correct. It's just that I'm not getting the results I want. I'm trying to find the sum of each column in a 3x2 2D Array and I'm getting this. 
Code Below:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class testa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] m = new double[3][2];
        //int b = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();

        double sum = 0;

        createArray();

        printResult(m, sum);
    }
    public static double[][] createArray() {
        double[][] bucky = new double[3][2];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int row = 0; row < bucky.length; row++) {

            for (int column = 0; column < bucky[row].length; column++) {

                bucky[row][column] = rand.nextInt(50);


                System.out.print(bucky[row][column] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            //return createArray();
        }
        return bucky;
    }

    public static double sumColumn(double[][] bucky, int columnIndex) {
        int sum = 0;
        ColumnIndex = 1
        for (int i = 0; i < bucky.length; i++) {
            sum += bucky[i][columnIndex];
            System.out.println(bucky[i][columnIndex] + "\n");

        }
        System.out.print(sum + "\n");

        return sum;
    }
    public static void printResult(double[][] bucky, double sum) {
        //System.out.printf("       ");
        for (int i = 0; i < bucky.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(sumColumn(bucky, i) + "   ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

output:

```
28.0  18.0  
12.0  9.0  
36.0  23.0  
0
0
0
0.0   0
0
0
0.0   0 
0
0
0.0
```

Also it would be nice to find out how to get a random number between 20-50 in the array.

Comment: `m` is an array created in `main`, and defaults to all `0` values. `createArray()` creates a *different* array and returns it, but **`main` ignores the returned value**, so the new array is discarded. You then pass the still-all-zeros array `m` to `printResult`, and you're confused that the values are all 0????

Comment: yea, im confused on why the sum is outputting 0 also can you tell me how to pass the array in the CreateArray Method .

Comment: `m = createArray();` --- You just have to assign the return value to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues in your code:

- `double[][] m = new double[3][2]` creates an array with all values equal to 0 then you call `createArray()` but that does not modify `m`
- When you call `printResult(m, sum)`, your m is still filled with zeros
- In your `printResult(double[][] bucky, double sum)` you are not using `sum` so it can simply be `printResult(double[][] bucky)`
- In `sumColumn(double[][] bucky, int columnIndex)`, you set `columnIndex = 1` so you are always summing the second column. It needs to be removed
- In `sumColumn(double[][] bucky, int columnIndex)`, you for loop is incorrect, you loop on `bucky.length`, this will loop on the rows, you need to take the first row (bucky[0]) and loop on its length: `for (int i = 0; i < bucky[0].length; i++)`
- Finally your logs are very hard to read, I changed them so we can see what is going on.

Here is your code, cleaned of these errors:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // create your array using your createArray method
  double[][] m = createArray();
  printResult(m);
}

public static double[][] createArray() {
  System.out.println("Create Array");
  double[][] bucky = new double[3][2];
  Random rand = new Random();
  for (int row = 0; row < bucky.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < bucky[row].length; column++) {
      bucky[row][column] = rand.nextInt(50);
      System.out.print(bucky[row][column] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
  return bucky;
}


public static void printResult(double[][] bucky) {
  System.out.println("Print Result");
  for (int i = 0; i < bucky[0].length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Column "+i);
    System.out.println(" => " + sumColumn(bucky, i));
  }
  System.out.println();
}

public static double sumColumn(double[][] bucky, int columnIndex) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < bucky.length; i++) {
    sum += bucky[i][columnIndex];
    System.out.print(bucky[i][columnIndex] + " ");
  }
  System.out.print(" => " + sum);

  return sum;
}
```

It prints out:

```
Create Array
13.0  25.0  
18.0  18.0  
23.0  38.0  
Print Result
Column 0
13.0 18.0 23.0  => 54 => 54.0
Column 1
25.0 18.0 38.0  => 81 => 81.0
```

Comment: how do i get rid of the numbers under column 0 and 1 i just needed the sum

Comment: @MichaelKofiAfriyie Remove the 2 `System.out.print` in `sumColumn`. If my answer solves your problem, please upvote and accept it